# is it possible to create shared_ptr for void*?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have class that can contains pointer to some data and type of his data.
So at each moment I can operate with this data using cast to proper type.

Here is example for int and float:

```
enum MyType {
    NO_TYPE,
    INT,
    FLO
};

class MyClass {
public:
    MyType type;
    void* data;

    MyClass(int i)
        :
            type(MyType::INT)
    {
        data = (void*) new int(i);
    }

    MyClass(float i)
        :
            type(MyType::FLO)
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor\n";
        data = (void*) new float(i);
    }

    MyClass()
        :
            type(MyType::NO_TYPE)
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor (default)\n";
        data = nullptr;
    }

    void Copy(const MyClass &from)
    {
        this->type = from.type;
        if (this->type == MyType::INT)
            this->data = (void*) new int (*((int*)from.data));
        if (this->type == MyType::FLO)
            this->data = (void*) new float (*((float*)from.data));
    }

    MyClass(MyClass &from) {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor\n";
        Copy((const MyClass&)from);
    }

    MyClass(const MyClass &from) {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor\n";
        Copy(from);
    }

    ~MyClass() {
        std::cout << "Destructor for type "  << this->type << "\n";
        if (this->type == MyType::INT)
            delete (int*)this->data;
        if (this->type == MyType::FLO)
            delete (float*)this->data;
        this->data = nullptr;
    }
};
```

I want to rewrite it with `shared_ptr`. But my main problem that `data` is `void*`. Is there is some techniques that may helps me?

**Update:**
Main purpose of writing this class is store some different data in one queue
like `queue<MyClass>`

Comment: `std::variant<std::monostate, int, float>` seems more appropriate.

Comment: @AlexF doesn't seem so if type is determined runtime

Comment: To answer your question, you may pass custom deleter.

Comment: I update question to show why I can't use templates.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::any` or `std::variant`?

Comment: Why do not to use type erasure technique?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't speak to the value of using a `shared_ptr<void>`, but it can serve as a generic container for a pointer.

These are valid:

```
int i = 42;
std::shared_ptr<void> spVoid = std::make_shared<int>(i);

float f = 3.14f;
std::shared_ptr<void> spVoid = std::make_shared<float>(f);
```

Correct destructor to the originally instantiated item will get invoked when the last reference goes away.  See it for yourself with a class instance.

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo destructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<void> spVoid = std::make_shared<Foo>();
    return 0;
}
```

The only warning I give with upcasting a shared_ptr is with regards to crossing DLL boundaries. The original type (and correct destructor) can get lost if shared_ptr instance is passed between DLL or shared library unit.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many unknowns to answer this unilaterally.

- If you know type before compilation, you can convert this class into a template.
- If you want type safety, you may use type-safe union - `std::variant`
- You may create a factory or visitor class that does allocation and separate classes for each storage
- If you need to store your data in monolithic array, e.g. to use wit some external, non-C++ API, e.g. OpenGL, you  must switch to `unsigned char*`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there is some techniques that may helps me?

You can certainly do that. Here's an updated version of your class with some test code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

enum MyType {
   NO_TYPE,
   INT,
   FLO
};

class MyClass {
   public:
      MyType type;
      std::shared_ptr<void> data;

      static void int_deleter(int* ptr)
      {
         std::cout << "Deleting an int*\n";
         delete ptr; 
      }

      static void float_deleter(float* ptr)
      {
         std::cout << "Deleting a float*\n";
         delete ptr;
      }

      MyClass(int i) : type(MyType::INT), data(new int(i), int_deleter)
      {
         std::cout << "Constructor with int\n";
      }

      MyClass(float i) : type(MyType::FLO), data(new float(i), float_deleter)
      {
         std::cout << "Constructor with float\n";
      }

      MyClass() : type(MyType::NO_TYPE)
      {
         std::cout << "Constructor (default)\n";
      }

      // Can be a private member function.
      static std::shared_ptr<void> make_data(const MyClass &from)
      {
         switch ( from.type )
         {
            case MyType::INT:
               return std::shared_ptr<void>(new int (*((int*)from.data.get())), int_deleter);

            case MyType::FLO:
               return std::shared_ptr<void>(new float (*((float*)from.data.get())), float_deleter);

            default:
               return {};
         }

         return {};
      }

      MyClass(MyClass &from) : type(from.type), data(make_data(from))
      {
         std::cout << "Copy constructor\n";
      }

      MyClass(const MyClass &from) : type(from.type), data(make_data(from))
      {
         std::cout << "Copy constructor\n";
      }

      ~MyClass()
      {
         std::cout << "Destructor for type "  << this->type << "\n";
      }
};

void test_int()
{
   MyClass c1(10);
   MyClass c2(c1);
}

void test_float()
{
   MyClass c1(10.2f);
   MyClass c2(c1);
}

int main()
{
   test_int();
   test_float();
}
```

Output:

```
Constructor with int
Copy constructor
Destructor for type 1
Deleting an int*
Destructor for type 1
Deleting an int*
Constructor with float
Copy constructor
Destructor for type 2
Deleting a float*
Destructor for type 2
Deleting a float*
```

Answer (score 0):

You might provide deleter: (and default one is correct so `std::make_shared` might be used).

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyType type = MyType::NO_TYPE;
    std::shared_ptr<void> data;

    MyClass() = default;

    MyClass(int i) { set(i); }
    MyClass(float f) { set(f); }

    void Copy(const MyClass &from)
    {
        switch (from.type) {
            case MyType::INT: set(*((int*)from.data.get());
            case MyType::FLO: set(*((float*)from.data.get());
            case MyType::NO_TYPE: set();
        }
    }

    MyClass(const MyClass &from) {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor\n";
        Copy(from);
    }

    void set()
    {
        type = MyType::NO_TYPE;
        data = nullptr;
    }

    void set(int i)
    {
        type = MyType::INT;
        data = std::make_shared<int>(i);
    }

    void set(float f)
    {
        type = MyType::FLO;
        data = std::make_shared<float>(f);
    }

    ~MyClass() = default;
};
```